# how to call a fragment from activity

Tags: android

I have to call a fragment class from an activity.  In the activity, i have to check the username and password before calling the fragment class.  When i click the login button, fragment class has to be loaded.  But, login layout is overlapped by the fragment layout.  How to remove the overlapping.

login.java

```
public class Login extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        } 
    }



  public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login, container,
                    false);

             return rootView;
        }

        public void onStart(){
            super.onStart();


               final Button loginButton = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.loginButton);

              loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    EditText editText1 = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                      EditText editText2 = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                      final String username = editText1.getText().toString();
                      final String password = editText2.getText().toString();

                     if (username.equals("user") && password.equals("user")){

                          Fragment1 fragment1 = new Fragment1();

                          getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                          .replace(android.R.id.content, fragment1).commit();

                         }       
                }
              });


}


    }
}
```

Fragment1.java

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment{
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container,false);
```

}
}

login.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
android:text="Username" />
<EditText
android:id="@+id/editText1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:ems="10" >

<requestFocus />
</EditText>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
android:text="Password" />
<EditText
android:id="@+id/editText2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:ems="10" >

</EditText>
</LinearLayout>

<Button
android:id="@+id/login"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Login" />

</LinearLayout>
```

fragment1.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<Button
android:id="@+id/login"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:onClick="goto"
android:text="Go to Main Activity" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try adding the ID to the root instead of calling `android.R.id.content` and see if replace now works as it should. This is just for testing purposes.

Comment: Please show how to add to the root. View.getRootView() gives root view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have two solutions for this :**

**1. Use one activity :** For this make two fragments, one for login and another for the afterlogin , then by default add the login fragmnet to the Activity container id and after login replace with the afterlogin fragment.

**2. Use Two Activities(One for login and one to contain the loginafter fragment) :** for this after login call the second activity and finish() the first activity.

Hope, This will work!

Comment: If i call finish(), application is getting closed.

Comment: Buddy, I have editted the answer , plz have a look and let me know If you are having any other problem.

Comment: I am using one activity and two fragments.  Now the setOnClickListener is not working when the button is clicked.  I have updated the code.  I am accessing the button in the placeholder fragment class.

Comment: setOnClickListener is working.  But the layouts are overlapped.

Comment: By default i am calling login fragment.  When button is clicked, i am calling fragment1.  Please check the code.  I have updated the code.  Still the layouts are overlapped when the login button is clicked.

Comment: For login fragment i am adding to R.id.container.  For Fragment1, i am replacing android.R.id.content.  Will this make a difference for replacing layout.

Comment: R.id.container and android.R.id.content makes the difference.  I have kept android.R.id.content for both the fragments.  Problem is solved.

Comment: Yes , ofcourse id should be same. It is great , your problem is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, fragment1).commit();
```

use

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, fragment1).commit();
```

`android.R.id.content` is the whole  container tat is displayed. You are trying to add content to already added one. You should use replace, which will remove the old content and add new one

**Edit:**

```
public class Login extends Activity
 implements PlaceholderFragment.LoginInterface{

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    } 
}


 public void login(){
              getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, new Fragment1()).commit();

 }



public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public interface LoginInterface{
           public void login();
    }

    loginInterface callback;
    public PlaceholderFragment(loginInterface cb) {
      this.callback = cb;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login, container,
                false);

         return rootView;
    }

    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();


           final Button loginButton = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.loginButton);

          loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                EditText editText1 = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                  EditText editText2 = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                  final String username = editText1.getText().toString();
                  final String password = editText2.getText().toString();

                 if (username.equals("user") && password.equals("user")){
                       this.callback.login();

                     }       
            }
          });

}
}
}
```

Comment: I have used replace.  Still the layouts are overlapped.  How to remove the overlapping.

Comment: if replaced, it wont overlap bcoz the old layout will be removed and `fragment1` will be added. tat is the functionality u r expecting?? :-/

Comment: even after using getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, fragment1).commit();    layouts are overlapped.  fragment layout is overlapped with the activity layout.

Comment: @user3715224 Either you're replacing the content of the wrong container or log-in fragment is being loaded from another portion of the code. Replace works 100% so something else is messing with your UI. Can you post more code? Format it please.

Comment: I have updated the code.  By default i am calling login fragment.  When button is clicked, i am calling fragment1.  Layouts are still overlapped.

Comment: Well, you have to do it differently.. you are trying to replace it from inside fragment, and thats the reason its overlapping

Comment: i have updated the code, try that. Also read this `http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html` you should be a expert after learning this :)